# Emulating the "notifications" style window on Facebook iPhone app?

Tags: iphone, three20

In Facebook's iPhone app, you can click "Notifications" at the bottom of the screen to display an animated view controller that slides up from the bottom of the screen, with a Done button to dismiss it. How do I implement the same type of view controller in Three20?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution to this in the TTNavigator sample app. I had forgotten this sample even exists!

The URL map in your AppDelegate must designate the specified URL as a modalViewController, e.g.:

```
[map from:@"tt://order?waitress=(initWithWaitress:)"
       toModalViewController:[ContentController class]];
```

The viewController that is being pushed must be *dismissed* as follows:

```
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```